# the MATLAB plot function is not plotting things

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I am attemping to plot a series of points on one single graph:

```
Klnvalue = [-1.516 -0.609 0.202 0.934 2.486 3.725 4.743 5.590];
temp = [3400 3600 3800 4000 4500 5000 5500 6000];
for i = 1:8
    eqn = ((nh^2)/(1-nh))*68.045964 == exp(Klnvalue(i));
    y = max(vpa(solve(eqn, nh)))
    x = temp(i);
    figure
    plot(x,y)
    hold on
end
```

But not only does eight graphs jumped out, not a single point is plotted, could you tell me why?

Comment: `plot` by default plots lines, and you are passing it a single point per iteration. Maybe substitute `plot(x,y,'+')`, or call `plot` just once outside the for-loop? Also, each call to `figure` creates a new figure; put that outside the loop.

Comment: Do `y(i) = ...` inside the loop, then `plot(temp, y)` after the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want 1 graph, pass something like figure(1). Also, take figure out of the loop and instead do:
figure(1), clf, hold on

```
 for i = 1:8
     eqn = ((nh^2)/(1-nh))*68.045964 == exp(Klnvalue(i));
     y = max(vpa(solve(eqn, nh)))
     x = temp(i);
     plot(x,y)
 end
```

Otherwise you waste time calling the figure each time even when it is still the current figure. Good luck!